# Conflict: osmnx and Spyder (Anaconda)

Tags: spyder, conflict, osmnx

I recently had to reinstall OSMNX. Following the instructions I deleted the "ox" environment where both osmnx and spyder have been previously installed.

I then proceeded with creating a fresh installation of osmnx following the online instructions. This generated a new "ox" environment with osnmx.

I then tried to install Spyder from Anaconda GUI in the ox environment, but it appears a conflict exists between spyder and ox and as such spyder can not be installed.

I am proficient with Matlab but (still) very poor with python (as you may guess). Any lead strongly appreciated.

Deleted ox environment where osmnx + spyder were installed
Uninstalled anaconda
Reinstalled anaconda
Reinstalled osmx through the environment creation protocol
Tried to reinstall spyder in the ox environment

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by literally following the installation instructions of osmnx package. Rather than sequentially perform operation (1) and (2) where (1) is creating a new environment in which osmnx is installed and (2) is adding spyder, I performed (1) and (2) togheter by running the following code:

conda create -n ox -c conda-forge --strict-channel-priority osmnx spyder

problem solved.